# Select row even if a condition is not true

Tags: sql

I don't know how to ask that also this is an example.
Say I have 2 tables:
pages:

```
idpage title
  0    first
  1    second
  2    third
```

reads:

```
idread idpage time
  50      0    8:15
  83      0    2:58
```

If I do `SELECT * FROM pages,reads WHERE pages.idpage=reads.idpage AND pages.idpage<2`

I will have something like that:

```
idpage title idread time
  0    first   50   8:15
  0    first   83   2:58
```

Where I would like that:

```
idpage title idread time
  0    first   50   8:15
  0    first   83   2:58
  1    second  0    0:00
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

What you need is a `LEFT JOIN`.  And, the way you are expressing the query makes this much harder to figure out.  So:

```
SELECT p.idpage, p.title,
       COALESCE(idread, 0) as idread,
       COALESCE(time, cast('0:00' as time)) as time
FROM pages p LEFT JOIN
     reads r
     ON p.idpage = r.idpage 
WHERE p.idpage < 2;
```

Note that when using `LEFT JOIN`, conditions on the *first* table should go in the `WHERE` clause.  Conditions on the *second* table go in the `ON` clause.

Comment: This will return null and that is not his desire output. You need a case statement.

Comment: @JVM - COALESCE is better than CASE

Comment: @Hogan it was select * when JVM posted the comment.

Comment: @sagi - COALESCE is still better than CASE

Comment: Didn't say its not, I just explained why JVM posted the answer, gordon didn't use coalesce at the time, he edited the answer since @Hogan

Comment: I validated this one because by 0 and 0:00 I mean null and Gordon seemed to understand that. Thanks

Comment: Correct @sagi. He modified his answer and pretended he had it the whole time.

Answer (score 2):

You need a left join and CASE expression to complete the values when they are null, like this:

```
SELECT p.*,
       case when r.idread is null then 0 else r.idread end as idread 
       case when r.time is null then '0:00' else r.time end as time 
FROM pages p
LEFT OUTER JOIN reads r
 ON(p.idpage = r.idpage)
WHERE p.idpage < 2
```

Note that I've changed your syntax to explicit join syntax(LEFT OUTER JOIN) instead of your implicit syntax's, which can easily lead to problems, especially when left joining.

Answer (score 1):

use full outer join

SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;